# Passing pydantic FieldType as an argument and checking with mypy

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic

I'm trying to use pydantic and mypy at the same time and I get an error when I try to pass a pydantic type as a function parameter.
What I want to do is the following :

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel

DataT = TypeVar("DataT")

class Result(GenericModel, Generic[DataT]):
    pageItems: DataT

class TypeA(BaseModel):
    id: str
    amount: float

class TypeB(BaseModel):
    id: str
    text: str

def generic_call_to_api(result_type: BaseModel, api_result: dict):
    res = Result[List[result_type]](**api_result)
    return res

a = {"pageItems": [{"id": "abc", "text": "def"}]}

print(generic_call_to_api(result_type=TypeB, api_result=a))
#>>>>>> pageItems=[TypeB(id='abc', text='def')]

print(generic_call_to_api(result_type=TypeA, api_result=a))
#>>>>>> pageItems -> 0 -> amount field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Depending of what I give in **result_type** I want pydantic to be able to "construct" the good type of variable.
What I tried was using `TypeVar[BaseModel]` or `Type[BaseModel]` but I still get this mypy error :

```
error: Variable "result_type" is not valid as a type
```

for the line : `res = Result[List[result_type]](**api_result)`

Surprinsigly the code is working though, depending on what I pass as an argument pydantic is able to correctly parse the requests response.

Any hint on how I can make it work ?

Comment: First of all, you're mixing type checking and runtime. `List[res_type]` is an **annotation**, it should not be instantiated (although python decided to allow it). You cannot use variable as annotation. It does not affect runtime behavior ans is equivalent to `list(**req.json())`. And this fails anyway, because `list` takes no kwargs (you're calling something like `list(x=1, y=2)` and it doesn't work). Please fix your code to be minimal, reproducible example: this cannot be working.

Comment: I edited my question to make it working, sorry I tried to reduce it to be more readable but it wasn't working indeed. I'm still confused by the difference between **annotations** and how pydantic works out the output type.

Comment: That's much better now! Now the problem is visible: `pydantic` uses `__class_getitem__` to perform some model fields resolution, and mypy interprets `SomeClass[something]` only as pure generic. You cannot parametrize generic with dynamic variable in static type checking context. I suggest either `if TYPE_CHECKING` block or `# type: ignore` comment. Since you don't annotate return type, you can safely ignore it. There is no way to satisfy `mypy` (well, maybe you can write plugin for that, but I don't know which hook to use and doubt that's worth it).

Comment: Maybe `__getitem__` on metaclass, not `__class_getitem__`, because `GenericModel` is older than `__class_getitem__`, but it doesn't matter here.

Comment: Ok, I'll choose the `# type: ignore` option in this case, thank you for the clarification !

Comment: And proper annotation is `generic_call_to_api(result_type: Type[BaseModel], api_result: dict[str, Any])`, because you pass type in the first place, not an instance.